# Posting a comment on friend's Facebook wall with an iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

i am new to ios development, i am struck with post a comment on ios application facebook account from ios app only. can you please guide me how to implement. thanks in advance.

Comment: best link forever http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_FRIEND_FB_ID/photos?access_token=%@", self.accessToken];

```
UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green-background.png"];
NSData *picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic, 1);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[newRequest setPostValue:@"This is Sample Text" forKey:@"message"];
[newRequest setData:picData forKey:@"data"];
[newRequest setPostValue:self.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[newRequest setDelegate:self];
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];
[newRequest startAsynchronous];
```